# How to search using the LIKE syntax and % WILDCARD % across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, search, wildcard, sql-like

How can you use mysql and the like/wildcard syntax across multiple tables, would it be as simple as:

```
(SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%tom%') AND (SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `name` LIKE '%sam%')
```

Not tested, just thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tables have the same structures, you can use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%tom%' UNION SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `name` LIKE '%sam%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION

```
(SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%tom%') UNION
 (SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `name` LIKE '%sam%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you use UNION, any duplicate rows may be removed. Use UNION ALL if you wish to retain any duplicates (say if you want to perform a COUNT on all rows matching %tom% in table1 and table2.

```
(SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%tom%') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `name` LIKE '%tom%')
```